# Do zero derivatives imply multiple zeros

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Let $W$ be a polynomial and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. If $W^{(i)}(a)=0$ for all $i\le n$ does that imply $(x-a)^{n+1} | W$? It obviously does for $n=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. If $n\geq0$ we can write $W=(x-a)^k P$ for some other polynomial $P$ with $P(a)\ne0$ and $k>0$. We then have $W'=k(x-a)^{k-1}P+(x-a)^kP'$, hence $W'(a)=0$ iff $k>1$. That means that if $n\geq1$ we have $(x-a)^2\mid W$. Similar for the higher powers.